# perlでExcelファイルの行数を取得したい。

Tags: perl

現在、perlのCGIプログラムの中で、Excel-2007ファイル(.xlsx)を読み込んで処理をしています。そのとき、CPANの
　Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new(ファイルパス);
を使用していますが、10000行以上のファイルであると、上記行の実行だけで１分を超えてしまいます。Webアプリなのでレスポンスが遅いのは致命的です。
Spreadsheet::XLSX 以外のパッケージで、処理が速いものが無いか探しましたが、まだ見つかっていません。
それが見つからない場合の代替として、件数が多い場合に上記行を実行しないというロジックも考えていますが、上記行を実行せずに件数を取得する方法を見出せていません。

perlにて、多数行のExcelを高速に読み込む、または高速に件数を取得できる手段があればお教え願います。

Answer (score 4):

ファイル名「hoge.xlsx」の<del>シート名</del>「sheet1」の行数をとる場合、こんな感じでしょうか。異常系はあまり考慮していないサンプルです。

SpreadSheet::XLSXの超簡易版なので、所要時間は同じぐらいかかってしまうかもしれません。

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip;

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
$zip->read('hoge.xlsx') == Archive::Zip::AZ_OK or die;
my $sheet1 = $zip->memberNamed('xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml') or die;
my $xml = $sheet1->contents;
my $rows = 0;
while ($xml =~ /<row r="(\d+)"/g) {
    $rows = $1 if $rows < $1;
}
print $rows, "\n";
```

#### 追記

argusさんのアドバイスと、Shimizuさんの「シート名を指定したい」という声を反映すると、こんな感じでしょうか。

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
no utf8;
use Archive::Zip;

my $xlsfile = 'hoge.xlsx';
my $sheetname = 'ほげシート';

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
$zip->read($xlsfile) == Archive::Zip::AZ_OK or die;

my $rels_xml = ($zip->memberNamed('xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels') or die)->contents;
my %rels = ();
while ($rels_xml =~ /\<Relationship(\s.*?)\/?\>/gs) {
    my $rels_elms = $1;
    $rels_elms =~ /\sTarget="(.*?)"/ or next;
    my $path = $1;
    $rels_elms =~ /\sId="(.*?)"/s or next;
    $rels {$1} = $path;
}

my $book_xml =($zip->memberNamed('xl/workbook.xml') or die)->contents;
my $rid;
while ($book_xml =~ /\<sheet(\s.*?)\/\>/gs) {
    my $book_elms = $1;
    if ($book_elms =~ /\sname="$sheetname"/so) {
        $book_elms =~ /\sr:id="([^"]+)"/s or die;
        $rid = $1;
        last;
    }
}
$rid or die;

my $sheet = $zip->memberNamed("xl/$rels{$rid}") or die;
$sheet->contents =~ /<dimension\s+ref="[A-Z]+(\d+):[A-Z]+(\d+)">/s or die;
print $2 - $1 + 1, "\n";
```

Comment: sheet*.xml の先頭に `<dimension ref="A1:G27"/>` などというノードがあるので、これをパースする方が良いかも知れません。

Comment: emasakaさんありがとうございます。

提示頂いたソースで高速件数カウントすることができました。
但し元のExcelファイルはユーザが任意で用意するもので、シート数は１と決まっていますが、シート名は「sheet1」とは限りません。任意のシート名でも対応できるようにする方法はあるでしょうか？

大変ありがとうございました。

Comment: 後から考えると「sheet1」はシート名ではありませんでした。そのため、シート数が1ならおそらsheet1でいいと思いますが、念のため、シート名からファイル名を調べる例を上に追記しました。